# how to do an alias in an antlr grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr3

Let's say I was trying to do a grammar for a simple JPA query syntax like so

```
select e from Entity e where e.name=:name and e.data>:time
```

Is there any documentation on how to do that alias part(the "e" basically)?

I am basically trying to get errors if the user types in

```
select a from Entity e where a.name=:name
```

Notice a is not defined so this should fail.  Should I be doing this in the grammar at all? or should I do it after the grammar is parsed when I walk the tree?

Comment: well, trying to figure out how I know/verify they are the same I guess.  It's not legal to have Entity a and then use "e".  or do I verify that AFTER all parsing is done(I guess I could go that route instead).

Comment: Ah, I see. That's clear. Could you perhaps make that clear in the original question as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I be doing this in the grammar at all?

What you should or shouldn't be doing is your business, of course :)

> or should I do it after the grammar is parsed when I walk the tree?

Yes, this is usually done while evaluating your AST, not during AST creation (so not during parsing).